# thumbnail on the blog

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem posting a thumbnail on the blog, if the thumbnail is image or video.

I need to define @if to check the field in the mine_tyme database if it is image / jpeg and display an html code and if it is not image / jped and it is video another html code should appear

```
<div class="col-12">
   <div class="carousel-4item pb-50 owl-drag">
      @foreach(\App\Posts::all() as $posts)
      <div class="item gallery-item gallery-style-1 padding-x2">
         <a href="{{ url('/tutoriale/') }}/{{ $posts->id }}/{{get_array_data($posts->slug) }}" class=""> 
            @if ($mime_type="image/jpeg"): 
               <{{get_array_data($posts->mime_type) }} loop muted autoplay class="item-img" src="../public/uploads/file_manager/{{ get_array_data($posts->cover_image) }}"  alt="Tutoriale cum sa creezi gratuit un site"></{{get_array_data($posts->mime_type) }}>                               
            @elseif
               <div style="padding:100% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{{ get_array_data($posts->video_url) }}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="Gene fir cu fir Brasov"></iframe></div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script></div>
           @endif
           <div class="item-title">
               <h4 class=""><strong class="">{{ get_array_data($posts->title, 5) }}</strong></h4>
               <p  class="text-secondary">{!! clean (get_array_data($posts->short_description, 20))!!}</p>
                                        
           </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@if ($posts->mime_type == ('image/jpeg'||'image/jpg'||'image/png'))
   <image  class="item-img" src="../public/uploads/file_manager/{{ get_array_data($posts->cover_image) }}"  alt="Tutoriale cum sa creezi gratuit un site"></image>                         
@else
   @if ($posts->mime_type == ('video/mp4'))
      <video loop muted autoplay class="item-img" src="../public/uploads/file_manager/{{ get_array_data($posts->cover_image) }}"  alt="Tutoriale cum sa creezi gratuit un site"></video> 
   @else
      <div style="padding:100% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{{ get_array_data($posts->video_url) }}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="Gene fir cu fir Brasov"></iframe></div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
  @endif                       
@endif
```

Comment: This isn't a valid solution